# La diferencia entre los verbos mantener, lograr y obtener

Tags: gramática, verbos, uso-de-palabras

> Él **logró** el carro de su hermano Pepito.
>
> Él **obtuvo** el carro de su hermano Pepito.
>
> Él **mantuvo** el carro de su hermano Pepito.

¿Son los tres verbos correctos en este contexto?

Comment: Son tres frases correctas pero ¿Cuál es el contexto?

Answer (score 3):

Sí, las tres frases son correctas, pero no significan lo mismo:

> Él logró el carro de su hermano Pepito.

Esta es la más rara de las tres y es raro encontrar el verbo 'lograr' en una frase así. La frase quiere decir que de alguna manera el sujeto consiguió el carro de su hermano como un premio, o a través de un proceso costoso. Lograr, obtener y conseguir son parecidos, pero lograr implica tal vez más a menudo que lo conseguido es algo especialmente valioso. De ahí que la palabra 'logro' sea como 'achievement' en inglés.

> Él obtuvo el carro de su hermano Pepito.

Esta es más común y puede indicar que él consiguió que alguien le diera el carro de su hermano, o que su propio hermano se lo dió, como en 'he got his brother's car'.

> Él mantuvo el carro de su hermano Pepito.

No tiene nada que ver con las anteriores salvo porque, ciertamente, para mantener algo hay que haberlo obtenido primero. Mantener quiere decir conservar algo y evitar que se estropee. Tal vez el hermano fue de viaje, o a la cárcel, y el sujeto guardó y cuidó su coche mientras tanto.

Otro verbo que es sinónimo de lograr y obtener es conseguir. Lograr y conseguir implica más que ha habido cierto esfuerzo en conseguir lo que se consigue/logra, mientras que obtener indica tal vez solamente un cambio de posesión: yo puedo obtener una casa porque la heredé de mis padres, sin que eso implique que yo haya hecho ningún esfuerzo por conseguirla. En cambio, si logro/consigo la casa, de alguna forma se da por hecho en la frase que he realizado algún esfuerzo por conseguir la casa.

Mantener, por otro lado, es otro verbo distinto y creo que es posible que lo hayas confundido con conseguir al escribir la pregunta... ¿Puede ser?